# Split tables into few pages

Tags: java, itext, pdfptable

I have data that I insert into a table of kind of PdfPTable.
The data contains of data belongs to few sources, and I should split the data to few pages so that each source will start in a new page.

```
--- 1st data source data ---
page break
--- 2nd data source data ---
page break
--- 3rd data source data ---
page break
```

what is the best solution? It seems like PdfPTable doesn't have a function that does so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually done using separate `PdfPTable` instance. One table for the 1st data source data, the next table for the 2nd data source data, and so on. If you look at the examples of [Chapter 4 of my book](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-4), you'll find an examples such as [HeaderFooter1](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-4#188-headerfooter1.java) and [HeaderFooter2](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-4#189-headerfooter2.java).

In these examples, we get information about a film festival. This film festival spans several days. We want to list all the movies screened on a specific day in a table and we want to start a new page when a new day starts:

```
List<Date> days = PojoFactory.getDays(connection);
for (Date day : days) {
    document.add(getTable(connection, day));
    document.newPage();
}
```

The `connection` is a database connection, whereas `day` is the parameter we'll use to perform a query. The `getTable()` method create a new `PdfPTable` for each set of movies shown on a particular day.

The page break you desire is achieved by invoking `document.newPage()` each time a `PdfPTable` with a certain data set has been added to the `document`.